# Programmatically retrieve the remote tracking branch of a local git branch

Tags: git

I can view the "remote" tracking branches (ex: `upstream/main`) by running:

```
git branch -vv
```

As an example:

```
$ git branch -vv
  testing-s3           f08dcfa s3 check testing
  main                 688f70b [remote-two/main] [OS-999] Fix regional issue 17
* release-22           468f72c [upstream/release-22] adapt region against main fork
  branch-test          b490963 [origin/branch-test] Grant only explicit strings
```

So, for the above example, `main` is tracking `remote-two/main` ^^

**I need to programmatically (one liner preferred) get the remote tracking branch of a specific branch.**
So, using the above example if I pass "main", the command/script would return the string `remote-two/main` -- how can I do this?

I was thinking something like `git branch -vv | grep main | cut ....`, however grep won't work since there is no guarantee the string isn't found elsewhere. Such as my above example that has the word "main" in the comments of a different branch.

Comment: What does `git show-ref main` show?

Comment: Or `git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' refs/heads/main` should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--list` option to select the desired branch and the `--format` option to customize the output to only contain the tracking information:

```
$ git branch --format "%(upstream:short)" --list main
remote-two/main
```

See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names) for further ways of customizing the output.

Comment: A+ thanks! Hadn't used `--format` before. Must have glossed over it